# What does the electrum wallet file contains?

Tags: wallet, electrum

I have been using electrum wallet and I heard that there exist a wallet file... but what does exactly contains? the private keys?

Answer (score 1):

> **I heard that there exist a wallet file**

According to https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#where-is-my-wallet-file-located

> The default wallet file is called default_wallet, which is created when you first run the application and is located in the /wallets folder, inside the datadir.

---

> **what does exactly contains? the private keys?**

It contains at least the seed and private keys

> How is the wallet encrypted?
>
> Electrum uses two separate levels of encryption:
>
> Your seed and private keys are encrypted using AES-256-CBC. The private keys are decrypted only briefly, when you need to sign a
> transaction; for this you need to enter your password. This is done in
> order to minimize the amount of time during which sensitive
> information is unencrypted in your computer’s memory.
>
> In addition, your wallet file may be encrypted on disk. Note that the wallet information will remain unencrypted in the memory of
> your computer for the duration of your session. If a wallet is
> encrypted, then its password will be required in order to open it.
> Note that the password will not be kept in memory; Electrum does not
> need it in order to save the wallet on disk, because it uses
> asymmetric encryption (ECIES).
>
> Wallet file encryption is activated by default since version 2.8. It
> is intended to protect your privacy, but also to prevent you from
> requesting bitcoins on a wallet that you do not control.

From what I have read, from version 2 the Electrum wallet file is in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format - so should be readable with a text editor / viewer.

If you see nothing other than unreadable [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) text (`A`–`Z` , `a`–`z` , `0`–`9` , `+` , `/` and `=`), it means the wallet is encrypted.